# Where is the Alias Editor/Manager in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, alias

I'm reading some documentation that mentions it. It says the Alias Manager is found under Configuration in the Menu Bar, but the Menu Bar is not an option for me unfortunately. The search has also been disabled.

Does anyone know where this manager actually is in the system? Or (and that would be even better) does anyone know the run command(s) for it?

Since the word "configuration" was mentioned I looked into System Configuration (Run > msconfig) > Tools tab, but it's not there.

Below is how its window looks like: [image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your screenshot is taken from a software called "[MutliCommander](http://multicommander.com/docs/aliases)". As such you will have to install it in order to use its features. That is not a general Windows feature.